# Is it possible to edit configmaps in kubernetes using api's?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I have a cluster name "**ba-test-k8s"** and have two namespaces linked with this cluster. (CORE and TOOLING). I execute my test cases in the TOOLING namespace and have to edit the config map present in the CORE namespace while execution. Please let me know how can I achieve this

Comment: you can write in your test cases to edit the config map across the namespaces however if user dont have access to the config or patch configmap it wont work.

Comment: _"tried using fabric8 but I'm getting forbidden error for the user. and we are not allowed to add more roles for that user – Shruti"_ Please share what you've done so far: a piece of code, the error message you get etc. Did you check on any client libraries that already have dedicated methods ? If you get forbidden error, probably without setting a service account with proper permissions you won't get any further.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the official API documentation for ConfigMaps? There are [PATCH](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#patch-configmap-v1-core) and [REPLACE](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#replace-configmap-v1-core) methods in there.

Comment: I have a cluster name "ba-test-k8s" and have two namespaces linked with this cluster. (CORE and TOOLING). I execute my test cases in TOOLING namespace and have to edit the configmap present in CORE namespace while execution. Please let me know how can I achieve this

Comment: @Shruti, please don't re-post your entire question as a comment. It doesn't help in anything.

Answer (score 0):

As Malt shared you can use the above methods and hit it using the **Curl** or command line **Kubectl**

if you are looking forward to automating the using any language you can use the client library with Python, Node and etc.

You can get the list of client libraries at  :https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/

Comment: @sharuti srna your test cases written in which language ? can you run kubectl to edit the configmap?

Comment: tried using fabric8 but I'm getting forbidden error for the user. and we are not allowed to add more roles for that user

Comment: we are using Springboot and java in our framework

Comment: okay got it. if user don't have access to update the config map it won't possible.

Comment: Okay got it. The I'll try first to get full access first. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Shruti what you can do is to try path the existing configmap if you can't edit it or creat it. might be possbile admin has added only patch permission